# Lock on existence of file in Java

Tags: java, file, locking

**Short version:** Why should [`File.createNewFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--) not be used for file locking? Or more specifically: Are there issues if it is used to lock an applications data directory?

---

**Details:**

I would like to protect my applications data directory using a lock file: If the file `lock` exists, the directory is locked and the application exits with an error message. If it does not exist it will be created and the application continues. On exit the file will be deleted.

The lock will not be created that often (i.e. performance is not an issue) and I have no problem with manually deleting the lock file in case of some error (i.e. failing to delete the file is not an issue).

The code looks something like this:

```
File lockFile = new File("lock");
boolean lockCreated = lockFile.createNewFile();
if (lockCreated)
{
    // do stuff
    lockFile.delete();
}
else
{
    System.err.println("Lockfile exists => please retry later");
    // alternative: Wait and retry e.g. 5 times
}
```

Now I'm a bit confused about the [Javadoc of `createNewFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--):

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. **The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic** with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the file.
>
> Note: **this method should *not* be used for file-locking, as the resulting protocol cannot be made to work reliably.** The [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) facility should be used instead.

What are the potential problems mentioned in the note, considering the existence check and file creation are atomic?

[This forum post](http://www.techtalkz.com/java/255171-what-wrong-file-createnewfile.html#post1008969) from December 2007 indicates there are "significant platform differences" according to the Javadoc of [File.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) (although I cannot find such a statement since at least Java SE 1.4.2). But even if there would be such differences: Could they really cause the locking to fail (i.e. two processes think the data directory is usable at the same time)?

---

**Note:** I do *not* want any of the following:

- Lock a file so that no other process can access and/or modify it (most information I found seems to discuss this issue).
- Make sure no other process can remove the lock.
- Synchronize multiple threads of the same JVM (although I think my solution should be able to handle that too).

Comment: depends on what they mean by "atomic". there's atomic-within-your-own-app, and atomic-for-all-apps-on-the-system. I'd suspect it's atomic for your app only, and can't do anything to protect some other parallel process jumping in and sniping the file away from you.

Comment: You could bail on using a file, and just open a port.

Comment: @MarcB: I expected the Javadoc to mean systemwide atomicity: "… _are a single operation that is atomic with respect to **all** other filesystem activities_…". But good point, did not think about that…

Comment: @MarkW: Good idea. But I think I'll stick to my file based solution, unless someone comes up with a reason not to. The application does not need to be bullet proof after all… ;-)

Comment: I looked at the jgit source code and they are using the same approach ([LockFile](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/internal/storage/file/LockFile.java)). As pointed out in another answer, I guess this is kind of valid for a local fs.

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc of [`Files.createFile(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-), part of [`java.nio.file`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) available since Java 7, repeats the promise of atomicity but does not mention anything about file based locking.

---

My reasoning:

- Either the newer method (from `java.nio.file.Files`) is affected by the same (or similar) problems as the older one (from `java.io.File`) and the Javadoc is simply missing this information…
- … or the newer method actually behaves more predictably and correct.

Given the error handling and specification in `java.nio.file` has generally been improved compared to the `File` class (existing ever since JDK 1.2), I assume the second alternative is correct.

---

My conclusion: Using `Files.createFile(…)` is fine for this use case.

Comment: Your conclusion could be clearer in my opinion: Do you suggest NOT using `File.createNewFile()` and ONLY `Files.createFile()` instead? Because not only is the note missing in Javadoc of the latter, but the implementation seems totally different as well. Even though in both cases calls seem to end in the same native calls using the same arguments: `File`: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/native/libjava/WinNTFileSystem_md.c#L569 `Files`: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsChannelFactory.java#L308

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: reliable file based locking in Java is not practical.

The long answer: The issue with file based locking, in any OS, always comes down to what kind of storage system the file comes from. Almost all network accessed file systems (NFS, SAMBA, etc) have very unreliable (or at least unpredictable) synchronizations on file creates or deletes that make a general Java-ish approach inadvisable. In certain OSes, using local file systems, you can sometimes get what you desire. But you need to understand the underlying file system and its characteristics and proceed with care.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand network file systems behave unpredictable. For me the Javadoc sounds pretty strict though. So either the Javadoc is correct and it is guaranteed that the check and file creation is atomic (at least for local file systems) or it is not and the Javadoc is wrong and should be reformulated (e.g. _on a best effort basis_…). Adding a rather unspecific note should not invalidate the guarantees made before…