# Why can't I use createNewFile for file locking?

Tags: java, file, concurrency, locking

The Javadoc for `createNewFile` states:

> Note: this method should not be used for file-locking, as the
>   resulting protocol cannot be made to work reliably. The `FileLock`
>   facility should be used instead.

What is the reason why `createNewFile` should not be used for file-locking, and what is the area of unreliability it refers to?

As far as I am concerned, `createNewFile` just creates a file, and I don't see why it could not be used as part of a locking mechanism. Let me describe my use case:

- Multiple machines all having access to a mounted filesystem and need to process/update a file (let's say `mydata.properties`) on an infrequent basis
- Each machine has just one thread in one process needing to access the file. Only conflict can be between different machines
- The relevant process may be running as the same user ID in different machines
- To preserve data consistency, only one machine can be processing/updating the file at one time (in other words, if one machine is doing processing then another machine cannot do updates)
- Machines are uniquely identified by their IP address

To implement this I had planned to implement a strategy like:

- When a machine starts to process the file it will create a lock file (such as `mydata.properties.lock`) containing the machine's IP address and current timestamp
- If the `createNewFile` method fails, assume some other machine is holding the lock and continue to wait for the lock to be released
- After some fixed timeout (after the timestamp in the lock file) just release the lock anyway (this is to cope with situations like when a machine takes the lock and then immediately crashes)
- Once the machine appears to hold the lock, double-check that its IP address was in the file (not sure if this step is necessary)
- After processing is complete, delete the file to release the lock

I am not sure why I can't use `createNewFile` in this case? I tried to read the documentation for `FileLock` recommended as the alternative, but I can't figure out how this mechanism could factor into my use case. I am not very familiar with "file channels" though, so I may have misunderstood.

Comment: Who says it will fail if the file already exists?

Comment: If the documentation says "don't try to use this for file-locking", don't use it for file-locking, even if you think it works.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850724/lock-on-existence-of-file-in-java .